# Check files out of PVCS with nant & nantconrib

Tags: nant, nantcontrib, pvcs

I'm taking my first steps with nant and nantcontrib so please bear with me!

The steps I would like to perform with nant are the following:

1. Get the latest files from PVCS
2. Check-out (i.e. for editing) the AssemblyInfo.cs so I can automatically take care of versioning etc.
3. Once the build has completed, check in AssemblyInfo.cs
4. Label all the files within the PVCS project with the version label.

I have had a look at the [nantcontrib help site](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/), however, there doesn't seem to be a mention of checking files out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice and simple (once you've located the PVCS directory!)

```
<pvcsget projectdatabase="${PVCS_Database}" userid="user" includesubprojects="true" lock="false">
    <entities>
        <!--Get everything!-->
        <entity name="/"/>
    </entities>
</pvcsget>
```